# WebAssembly Image manipulation with ClojureScript

Tags: webassembly, clojurescript

Request detail:

We want to do some image manipulation and conversion, in the browser.
We prefer WebAssembly, because of its runtime efficiency.
We want to use ImageMagick, because it can read SVG, Ai, and other formats that we want to work with.
Our project is written in ClojureScript, compiled with Shadow-cljs.

Some libraries that we tried (this > https://github.com/dlemstra/magick-wasm) this is the error I get:

```
Closure compilation failed with 1 errors
--- node_modules/@imagemagick/magick-wasm/dist/index.umd.js:21
Transpilation of 'This or super in instance member' is not yet implemented.
```

or can't read SVG (this > https://github.com/KnicKnic/WASM-ImageMagick, even though it was a wrapper on ImageMagick)

or doesn't compile (this > https://silvia-odwyer.github.io/photon/ google-closure, which is part of Shadow-cljs ecosystem, returns error) this is the error I get:

```
Failed to inspect file
  /path-to-project/node_modules/@silvia-odwyer/photon/photon_rs_bg.wasm

it was required from
  /path-to-project/node_modules/@silvia-odwyer/photon/photon_rs.js

Errors encountered while trying to parse file
  /path-to-project/node_modules/@silvia-odwyer/photon/photon_rs_bg.wasm
  {:line 1, :column 0, :message "Character '' (U+0000) is not a valid identifier start char"}
```

The photon_rs_bg.wasm file exists, and permissions are correct.

Can you help us on this matter or propose another better approach to image manipulation with ClojureScript?

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: Thanks for response, I updated the question @cfrick, let me know if you need more details

Comment: You're not trying to compile wasm by shadow-cljs, are you?

Comment: I'm trying to :require a JS library that has a compiled .wasm file inside it, and get the errors in my question. .wasm file is in my node_modules dir, and got downloaded by running npm install @akond

Answer (score 1):

shadow-cljs currently does not support bundling `.wasm` files.

You can setup and use webpack to do the JS/WASM bundling instead via [:js-provider :external](https://shadow-cljs.github.io/docs/UsersGuide.html#js-provider-external).